# Xamarin Android warnings XA0106, Can not remove such hundreds of warnings

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

My target mono android version is 8.0 and i am building my app at API level 26
while building droid i am getting about 500 warnings related to nuget packages
in Android and IOS is OK.... 
something like this...

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1476,2): warning XA0106: Skipping BMS.Droid.Resource.Animation.design_fab_in. Please check that your Nuget Package versions are compatible.
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1476,2): warning XA0106: Skipping BMS.Droid.Resource.Animation.design_fab_out. Please check that your Nuget Package versions are compatible.
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1476,2): warning XA0106: Skipping BMS.Droid.Resource.Attribute.MediaRouteControllerWindowBackground. Please check that your Nuget Package versions are compatible.
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1476,2): warning XA0106: Skipping BMS.Droid.Resource.Attribute.mediaRouteBluetoothIconDrawable. Please check that your Nuget Package versions are compatible.
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1476,2): warning XA0106: Skipping BMS.Droid.Resource.Attribute.mediaRouteCastDrawable. Please check that your Nuget Package versions are compatible.
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1476,2): warning XA0106: Skipping BMS.Droid.Resource.Attribute.mediaRouteChooserPrimaryTextStyle. Please check that your Nuget Package versions are compatible.
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1476,2): warning XA0106: Skipping BMS.Droid.Resource.Attribute.mediaRouteChooserSecondaryTextStyle. Please check that your Nuget Package versions are compatible.
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1476,2): warning XA0106: Skipping BMS.Droid.Resource.Attribute.mediaRouteCollapseGroupDrawable. Please check that your Nuget Package versions are compatible.
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1476,2): warning XA0106: Skipping BMS.Droid.Resource.Attribute.mediaRouteConnectingDrawable. Please check that your Nuget Package versions are compatible.
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1476,2): warning XA0106: Skipping BMS.Droid.Resource.Attribute.mediaRouteControllerPrimaryTextStyle. Please check that your Nuget Package versions are compatible.
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1476,2): warning XA0106: Skipping BMS.Droid.Resource.Attribute.mediaRouteControllerSecondaryTextStyle. Please check that your Nuget Package versions are compatible.
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1476,2): warning XA0106: Skipping BMS.Droid.Resource.Attribute.mediaRouteControllerTitleTextStyle. Please check that your Nuget Package versions are compatible.
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1476,2): warning XA0106: Skipping BMS.Droid.Resource.Attribute.mediaRouteExpandGroupDrawable. Please check that your Nuget Package versions are compatible.
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1476,2): warning XA0106: Skipping BMS.Droid.Resource.Attribute.mediaRouteOffDrawable. Please check that your Nuget Package versions are compatible.
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1476,2): warning XA0106: Skipping BMS.Droid.Resource.Attribute.mediaRouteOnDrawable. Please check that your Nuget Package versions are compatible.
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1476,2): warning XA0106: Skipping BMS.Droid.Resource.Boolean.abc_action_bar_embed_tabs_pre_jb. Please check that your Nuget Package versions are compatible.
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1476,2): warning XA0106: Skipping BMS.Droid.Resource.Boolean.abc_action_bar_expanded_action_views_exclusive. Please check that your Nuget Package versions are compatible.
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1476,2): warning XA0106: Skipping BMS.Droid.Resource.Boolean.abc_config_allowActionMenuItemTextWithIcon. Please check that your Nuget Package versions are compatible.
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1476,2): warning XA0106: Skipping BMS.Droid.Resource.Color.design_textinput_error_color_dark. Please check that your Nuget Package versions are compatible.
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1476,2): warning XA0106: Skipping BMS.Droid.Resource.Color.design_textinput_error_color_light. Please check that your Nuget Package versions are compatible.
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1476,2): warning XA0106: Skipping BMS.Droid.Resource.Color.hint_foreground_material_dark. Please check that your Nuget Package versions are compatible.
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1476,2): warning XA0106: Skipping BMS.Droid.Resource.Color.hint_foreground_material_light. Please check that your Nuget Package versions are compatible.
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1476,2): warning XA0106: Skipping BMS.Droid.Resource.Dimension.abc_dialog_list_padding_vertical_material. Please check that your Nuget Package versions are compatible.
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1476,2): warning XA0106: Skipping BMS.Droid.Resource.Dimension.abc_search_view_text_min_width. Please check that your Nuget Package versions are compatible.
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1476,2): warning XA0106: Skipping BMS.Droid.Resource.Dimension.design_bottom_sheet_modal_peek_height. Please check that your Nuget Package versions are compatible.
```

Comment: Your question being..?

Comment: How to remove these warnings from project?

Comment: Try right clicking in the Solution Explorer on the Solution and select "Manage NuGet Packages for Solution". [An introduction to NuGet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/what-is-nuget)

Comment: How it will remove warnings from the project, do i need to update some sort of nuget packages?

Comment: @Benl: nice try but unfortunately, this doesn't help. This is a known superfluous warning that cannot be disabled and the app will compile without the slightest problems. Just noise, nothing else. It bothers an endless number of people (eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48659082/identifying-culprits-for-numerous-xa0106-warnings-when-building-xamarin-forms-ap) and I'm yet to find an answer anywhere.

Comment: Maybe an answer to why [a lot of warnings appears](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/272488/#Comment_272488)

Comment: @Benl: unfortunately, I'm not sure it's that simple. I'm helping a package author to find out what's causing it and I get tons of warnings despite the fact that both the package and my app use the very same support package versions.

Comment: same issue here. Have you discovered any solution?

Answer (score 2):

These non-actionable warnings can be suppressed by editing the following into the Android project file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <MSBuildWarningsAsMessages>XA0106</MSBuildWarningsAsMessages>
</PropertyGroup>
```

As of [Visual Studio 16.3 Preview 1](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/606610/xamarinandroid-xa0106-warnings-cant-be-suppressed.html), these have been downgraded to messages instead of warnings, so suppression will no longer be necessary. More background is available on the [Xamarin.Android GitHub](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/1988).